# Случайное число в пределах от 0.5 до 1.5

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Как можно сделать random от 0.5 до 1.5.
Пытаюсь сделать `Math.random() + 1.5` всегда возвращает 1.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double d=Math.random()+0.5;
```

Это если слово "ДО" в твоём предложении означает "исключительно ДО".

Comment: @argamidon если это делаю в цикле, то выдает разные значения от 0.5 до 1.5, а вот если запускать его только один раз в методе, то всегда выдает 0.5 хоть сто раз.

Comment: Ну, может, код покажешь? У меня **этот** код выполняется нормально. Каждый раз новое значение.

Comment: @argamidon

    double d=Math.random()+0.5;

у меня всегда так было с рандомом, если просто Math.random(), то всегда выдает 0, если не запускать его в цикле.

Comment: к int'у случайно не приводишь?

Comment: @argamidon да, вы правы, в цикле я запускал `System.out.println(Math.random)`, а в методе я приводил его в long, я всю жизнь не понимал, почему со мной такое западло)) и не обращал на это внимания, так как было нетрудно обойтись и без рандома)